# The type of the target device does not match the deviceType configured in the config.json file of the selected module

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to do development in HarmonyOS (DevEco, HAP, certificates, project structure, etc...). Right now, I'm stuck on trying to run a test application on a test device.

A few days ago I managed to get the Lite Wearable simulator running, but now it does not want to run anymore, when I launch the device manager and login with my Huawei developer account, all I get is "Unable to obtain the remote emulators: Network connection failure. Check the network connection or HTTP Proxy settings." However, I know there are no issues with my network and I'm not using any proxy.

Since the simulator is not working, I tried to plug my phone through USB and enable ADB, and I can see my phone listed in DevEco as a valid device for running code, however, when I try to run a test app I receive the error "The type of the target device does not match the deviceType configured in the config.json file of the selected module.", which does not make sense because I added all possible devices into the config.json file

[image]

Finally, I tried to create a HAP file so I can install the app on my Huawei Watch GT 3, but when I try to install the app with the DevEco assistant, I receive the error "Installation failed: Failed to decompress name_of_the_app"

I need help running a test app using any of these methods (Simulator or real device) before I spend anytime building the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading [this article](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/basic-config-file-elements-0000000000034463) and found that the deviceType attribute could contain the value "liteWearable", which I've never heard of and was missing from my config.json.

I added this missing value and now I can successfully execute the simulator, which makes sense since it is a "Huawei Lite Wearable Simulator"